# Buchi arithmetic meaning

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, automata, arithmetic, buchi-automata

I am studying [this](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/christoph.haase/home/publication/ghw-19/ghw-19.pdf) article. But I have trouble with understanding the Buchi arithmetic. It says in section IV:

> ... Formulas in this fragment generalise classical integer programming and are of the form
> $$
> \mathbf{A} \boldsymbol{x}=\boldsymbol{c} \wedge \bigwedge_{i \in I} V_{p}\left(x_{i}\right)=y_{i}
> $$

But I don't understand what does it mean by
$
\mathbf{A} \boldsymbol{x}=\boldsymbol{c} \wedge \bigwedge_{i \in I} V_{p}\left(x_{i}\right)=y_{i}
$. I know that the goal is to finding $\boldsymbol{x}$ such that was an answer for previous equation. But my question is about the meaning of $\boldsymbol{c} \wedge \bigwedge_{i \in I} V_{p}\left(x_{i}\right)=y_{i}$. According to the previous sections of the article $\boldsymbol{c}$ is a vector and I want to know what does wedge symbol mean in this case?

In addition, I want to know, as $V_{p}\left(x_{i}\right)$ is an integer, is the big wedge notation here a bitwise and or something else?

As It is the first time I have studied this kind of material, my question may seem naive. However, I appreciate any help containing some references about Buchi arithmetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wedge sign means *AND*. The formula states that $\mathbf{A}x=c$ and for all $i \in I$, $V_p(x_i) = y_i$.